plot mean square error for training validation and testing in neural network
Hi I see many of mean square error (MSE) plot as shown below:

My understanding to generate blue line (training) as below:
Optimize the weights and bias values by using a certain optimization algorithm. For every epoch, calculate the MSE.
However, I don't understand how to generate the green and red lines.

Do you understand the purpose of the validation and test data?
Let's say you're training a neural network on 100,000 pieces of data. You should randomly split them into. Train(60,000), Validation(20,000), and Test(20,000).
The training data is what the network is actually trained out, the validation data is what checked against at each epoch: This is done to prevent overfitting on training data, and optimize hyperparameters.
At the very end, you can test the network against the test data, which is another test against overfitting.

It means during training is running, the MSE for training, validation and testing data for every iteration is calculated?

No testing doesn't get run until the end, but at the end it can go back and be run at each checkpoint to provide a graph.

From my understanding, the MSE of testing is evaluated after the model is fully trained. It means the MSE is just a single point. But how come the red line showing a curve. Sorry I am new in neural network
